# Compare value of NSInteger in Swift against code property in NSError?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In Swift, we need to compare the `code` property from a `NSError` object against a `NSInteger` value stored in a `NS_ENUM`.

The NS_ENUM struct (from https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision/blob/master/Source/PBJVision.h):

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PBJVisionErrorType)
{
    PBJVisionErrorUnknown = -1,
    PBJVisionErrorCancelled = 100,
    PBJVisionErrorSessionFailed = 101,
    PBJVisionErrorBadOutputFile = 102,
    PBJVisionErrorOutputFileExists = 103,
    PBJVisionErrorCaptureFailed = 104,
};
```

We want to see if the error code matches `PBJVisionErrorCancelled`, but we can't figure out the syntax in Swift.

After reading other SO posts and exploring multiple blog posts, there were several options tried but none worked:

```
Int(error!.code) == Int(PBJVisionErrorType.Cancelled)
Int(error!.code) == Int(PBJVisionErrorType.Cancelled.value)
error!.code == Int(PBJVisionErrorType.Cancelled)
error!.code == Int(PBJVisionErrorType.Cancelled.value)
error!.code == PBJVisionErrorType.Cancelled.value
```

What's the right syntax?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the solution to the referenced question works here as well. Otherwise let me know and I'll reopen it.